# How i can use FileInputStream getclass().getresource() for load txt file in jar

Tags: java, fileinputstream

How i can load txt file in jar?
cant use `getClass().getResource("/DataBase.txt");`

```
public static void readFromFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException{

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        Authorisation.userMap = (HashMap<String, User>) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
    }
```

Comment: can you tell me the structure of your `jar` file. I think file is not available at path you are trying to access.

Comment: Why can't you use getResource()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not reading an actual file, use :

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/DataBase.txt");
ObjectInputStream ios = new ObjectInputStream(in);
```

Comment: How i can use BufferedReader if i use Serializable? Method readLine() is not suitable